# storing data related to 'ng-repeat'ed items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a site showing a list of comments and the comments can be liked by clicking a button.
The site is written using angular and the list of comments are fetched from a node back end and rendered using `ng-repeat` of Angular.
To record a like I need to pass some information related to the comment to the node endpoint via AJAX.

The problem is that I don't wanna store any information related to the comment on the DOM. And I did not get how I can use jQuery.data here since I am '`ng-repeat`'ing to render the comments.

Please suggest some alternatives..

Here is how the comments are rendered

```
<div class="stickyNotes" ng-repeat="comment in commentList1">
     <p>
        {{comment.commentContent}}
     </p>
     <div>
        <a href=""><img src="../resources/images/thumb.png" class="upvoteImage" /> </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need atleast comment id in the DOM. For example <a href="/comment/{{comment.ID}}/upvote"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $index, and pass it to your controller method onClick. Then you can access the exact comment $scope.commentList1[index] on your controller, and do what you what with it.

you can learn about $index here:

```
https://thinkster.io/egghead/index-event-log
```

Comment: Really did not know much about $index and $log, but they are very useful.